# What is the name of this musical scale?

Tags: classical-music

In the last photo of [this instagram video](https://www.instagram.com/p/BLj7NzkDpC1/) there is a music scale

[image]

What is the name of this musical scale?

Answer (score 3):

It is the fifth mode of the Double Harmonic Scale.

However my western ears tend to hear a tonal center around E not B, which would make it the tonic scale (Double Harmonic).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale

Answer (score 0):

All my sources on scales love to cite [Twentieth-Century Harmony](http://www.thereelscore.com/PortfolioStuff/PDFFiles/PersichettiNotes.pdf), so I'll do it to.  According to [Vincent Persichetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_Persichetti), that is an "Oriental Scale."  This scale is based around the pattern H A2 H H A2 A2 W (H=Halfstep W=Wholestep A2= Augmented second)  See page 22 of the book linked in this answer for this more.

Comment: The pattern actually is H A2 H H A2 H W (so the last A2 in your patterns should be a H).